# Value of $S_{10}+I_{10}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{1}{k}$ and$$I_n=\int_{1}^{n}   \frac{x-[x]}{x^2}  dx$$ then what is the value of $S_{10}+I_{10}$ ?
$S_{10}=1+1/2+1/3+.....+1/10$  and $$I_{10}=\int_{1}^{10}   \frac{x-[x]}{x^2}  dx$$
$$=ln 10-\int_{1}^{10}   \frac{[x]}{x^2}  dx$$
But I am stuck here.How to proceed further?

Comment: $\int_{1}^{10}   \frac{[x]}{x^2}  dx=-1/2-2/3-...-9/10+9.$

Comment: Is this a GATE question ?

Comment: Yes asked in gate 2016.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use 
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{10}   \frac{[x]}{x^2}  dx & =\int_1^2\frac{1}{x^2}  dx+2\int_2^3\frac{1}{x^2}  dx +3\int_3^4\frac{1}{x^2}  dx+\cdots +9\int_9^{10}\frac{1}{x^2}  dx \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{9} k \int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{x^2}  dx \\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{9} k [-\tfrac{1}{u}]_k^{k+1} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{9} k\big( \tfrac{1}{k} -\tfrac{1}{k+1}\big) \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{9} 1 -(1 -\tfrac{1}{k+1})\\
&= \sum_{k'=2}^{10}\tfrac{1}{k'} = S_{10}-1
\end{align*}
$$

Since $[x]=k$ on each interval $[k,k+1)$ ; you see that it is easy to generalize for other indices values than 10... (and $S_n+I_n=S_N+(\ln(n)-S_n+1)=\ln(n)+1)$.

Comment: Thanks,I got the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another similar approach is to use the [Abel summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}1\cdot\frac{1}{k}=1+\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left[t\right]}{t^{2}}dt.$$